# CSS change child colors based on math?

Tags: css, dynamic, colors

Alright, I'll admit that title seems a bit cryptic, but here's the situation:

I have a list of actors on a page with photos and short bios, each one is its own <div>.  Let's say that I have seven actors on my page, and I want the text colors in their boxes to change, say, to create a rainbow, so actor 1 would be red, 2 would be orange, 3 would be yellow, and so on.  Can I do this without having to manually specify style="color:rgb(whatever)" on every div?  Let's say I want the color values to change dynamically if I add more people to the list or take them away, so I'd specify a beginning color value of rgb(255,0,0) for red and and end value of rgb(255,0,255) for violet and somehow fill in the rest, so that each subsequent box has a different text color but all together they make a rainbow.

...or would I be forced to use JavaScript to do this?

Comment: You would get most of the way with the new `nth-child` selectors.

Comment: @ralph.m how exactly would you achieve this with `nth-child`? How would you specify a dynamic increment of the "Blue" element in the RGB color scheme? HTML6?

Comment: u can use LESS or SCSS for this operation, so u don't have to do it manually everytime or if you want completely dynamic then you have to use JavaScript or jquery.

Answer (score 0):

No you need not required to red color manually you can use CSS nth-child selectors please check below tutorial

Click [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)!

Comment: I am not saying the link is not helpful but please don't post link only answers because they would lose their value if the linked page was to become unavailable. Instead, add at least a sample code to your answer.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me, from next time i will surely add sample code :)